# Adding new page into Rails 4 Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have new Rails project, in the project I have a controller, view and model named as `Customer`. Now, what I need is that beside the `CRUD` actions I need to add two new pages like:

```
1. http://0.0.0.0:3000/Customer/sale

2. http://0.0.0.0:3000/Customer/lease
```

And I want to insert code in these files.
How do I achieve this I mean creating new `sale` and `lease` links?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `routes.rb` file you can add these two routes:

```
  resources :customers do
    collection do
      get 'create_sale' => 'customers#create_sale', as: :create_sale
      get 'create_lease' => 'customers#create_lease', as: :create_lease
    end
  end
```

Then, you can add two new methods (actions) in your `customers_controller.rb` file:

```
  def create_sale
    # your logic goes here
  end

  def create_lease
    # your logic goes here
  end
```

and also create two views for them in the `app/views/customers/` directory as `create_sale.html.erb` and `create_lease.html.erb` where you will put your view related code.

Comment: @K M Rakibul Islam : Thank you Rakib :) Your suggestion has worked for me with some slight changes in the code in my application, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :customers do
   %w(sale lease).each do |route|
      get route.to_sym, action: route.to_sym, as: route.to_sym
   end
end
```

This will give you the ability to call the following controller actions:

```
#app/controllers/customers_controller.rb
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
    def sale
    end

    def lease
    end
end
```

---

**Nested Resources**

As an aside, there is something you should consider.

> I mean creating new `sale` and `lease`

If you want to create new sales or leases for your `Customer`, you may be better looking into [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

You must remember that Rails is object orientated. The controllers are meant to give you the ability to [`CRUD`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running) specific objects - IE create, edit, update, destroy, etc.

--

I see many people asking how they can "add" methods to controllers. This is not a problem. Problem rise, however, when you're trying to include `create` methods in a scope where they *don't* belong.

You need to keep your application as modular as possible. As such, you need to be able to extend any functionality into their correct places:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :customers do
    resources :leases, controller: :purchases, {type: :lease}
    resources :sales, controller: :purchases, {type: :sale}
end

#app/controllers/purchases_controller.rb
class PurchasesController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @customer = Customer.find params[:customer_id]
      @purchase = @customer.purchases.new(type: params[:type])
   end
   def create
      @customer = Customer.find params[:customer_id]
      @purchase = @customer.purchases.new purchase_params
   end

   private

   def purchase_params
      params.require(:purchase).permit(:type, :customer_id :etc, :etc)
   end
end

#app/models/purchase.rb
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :customer
end

#app/models/customer.rb
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :purchases
end
```

If you felt really adventurous, you'd be able to use [STI (Single Table Inheritance)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html) to create different instances of the same class type for `Sale` and `Lease`:

```
#app/models/sale.rb
class Sale < Purchase
end

#app/models/lease.rb
class Lease < Purchase
end
```

I could explain more about this if you wanted.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rich, You helped me in finding out a new and more concise method to solve my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

i think its better to use the resource

just an example, because i didn't know how you decide between sale and lease customer

routes:

```
resources :customers
```

and give the `index route` a parameter to get all `sale` and `lease customers` like

customercontroller

```
def index
  customer_type = params[:customer_type] || ['sale','lease']
  @customers = Customer.where(customer_type: customer_type)
end
```

and use this in your views

```
customers_path(customer_type: 'sale')
```

Comment: thank you Rob, I have mixed the above suggested method of @K M Rakibul Islam and your suggested "using resource" method and I got my problem solved.